# JavaFX draggable DnD components

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

I'm a noob as regards Java (mainly coded in PHP) and wanted to make a desktop application where different components could be drag and dropped into a linear flow. When a component was dragged in I was hoping that the flow of current components would give visual feedback and make way for the new component.

Example:

[image]

I was also hoping to use the same draggable code to re-shuffle placed components. The orange area to the left would be for dragging and dropping.

There is good information about [Drag-and-Drop in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) but I haven't found anything in JavaFX. I was hoping for pointers on how I could approach this please.

A follow-up question would be dropping into a hierarchy but I wanted to crawl before I walk and just try to get it working in a linear list (unless this is easy to implement in a tree hierarchy).

And finally I was hoping to keep the data in a form that could then be read and written to XML - not sure if this requirement would have any bearing on its draggability.

Hope someone can give me some pointers.

Comment: There is a very good tutorial for JavaFX DND operations at oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag_drop_feature.htm

Comment: Excellent. :) Thank you. This should help get me over the dnd hurdles.